# SQL Help how to restrict query to the 2 weeks of run

Tags: sql, sql-server

the query

```
SELECT TOP 10
    total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
        ,execution_count
        ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
        ,(SELECT
              SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                                                           WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                                                           ELSE statement_end_offset 
                                                       END -statement_start_offset)/2
                       ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
         ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
ORDER BY AVG_Run_Time DESC
```

can someone help me how to code it for the last two weeks of run

https://gyazo.com/4f79c9670f3281a8ac5342cdaee28951

table results example

**Avg_CPU_Time**    **execution_count** **AVG_Run_Time**    **query_text**
16182805    7   479013574    select   x.database_id as iDatabaseID   ,@sDatabase as sDatabase   ,x.[object_id] as iTableID   ,x.index_id as iIndexID   ,cast(sum(case when x.alloc_unit_type_desc = 'LOB_DATA' then 0 else x.page_count end) / 128. as decimal(9,3)) as nInRowMB   ,cast(sum(case when x.alloc_unit_type_desc = 'LOB_DATA' then x.page_count else 0 end) / 128. as decimal(9,3)) as nLobMB   ,cast(sum(x.page_count) / 128. as decimal(9,3)) as nTotalMB   ,cast(max(x.avg_fragmentation_in_percent) as decimal(5,2)) as nLogicalFragmentation  into   #index  from   #table as t    cross apply Metadata.dbo.udm_db_index_physical_stats_tvf(t.iDatabaseID, t.iTableID, null, null, 'sampled') as x  group by   database_id   ,[object_id]   ,index_
26520575    2   50647402     select  a.AccountID  , a.EndDate  , ax.[357A020C-EF75-42FD-92B0-3AA2F1F0B4D8]  , ax.[585EEDB4-68F6-4C62-ACDA-6FEE57144DB1]    into ZTemp_OngoingCanxProcess_AccsToUpdate    from Account a  join AccountEx ax on ax.AccountID = a.AccountID  join AccountTemplate at on at.AccountTemplateID = a.AccountTemplateID  where isnull(at.isongoing,0) = 0  and (ax.[357A020C-EF75-42FD-92B0-3AA2F1F0B4D8] is null and ax.[585EEDB4-68F6-4C62-ACDA-6FEE57144DB1] is null)  and (a.EndDate is not null and a.EndDate < cast(getdate() as date

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific in several ways.)

Comment: We need more explanation like : what is this query for, what you mean by 'for the last two weeks of run', what is the table(s) columns...

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: I'm using SQL server management studio

https://gyazo.com/4f79c9670f3281a8ac5342cdaee28951

these are the results for the code

Answer (score 0):

sys.dm_exec_query_stats is a MS SQL specific dynamic management view and the rows lifetime is bound with plan cache itself. As soon as the plan cache is dropped, the results that you found will be dropped.  You can however, store the results in seperate table for two weeks. But you will still schedule your query to run in certain intervals and insert new rows with a time stamp so you can understand when it was captured.

I would instead recommend query store if your sql server version is 2016 or newer